# Use a batch script to check an exe is open and loop til closed

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script created by a program I use which runs a job through.  I now need to wrap this up, and one of things I need to check is if the program is already open.  If it is, rather than closing it, I need to loop through, re-checking, until it closes automatically.  Then I can move onto the next section of the script.  I've found how to check for open, but can't work out how to add the extra in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') Do set "CR=%%a"

:FindAgain
set prog=Winword.exe
for /f %%a in ('tasklist /FI "Imagename eq %prog%"^|Find /i "%prog%"') do (
  set /a cnt+=1
  if not errorlevel 1 set /P"=%prog% is running !cnt!!CR!"<NUL:
  ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
  goto :FindAgain)
echo %prog% closed continuing..
```

Comment: You're welcome. Would you consider clicking the checkmark to let future visitors know this is a valid answer. Thanks